# Get Count Of Nested Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get count of Employees in a specific State in LINQ.

I have something like this :

```
States
     |
     Cities
          |
          Posts
              |
              Employees
```

How can I get `Employees` count by selected `State` in hand?

My Entities are :

```
public class Province : EntityBase
{
    public String ProvinceName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City : EntityBase
{
    public String CityName { get; set; }

    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Post> ElectricPosts { get; set; }
}

public class Post : EntityBase
{
    public String PostName { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public virtual String FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual String SureName { get; set; }
    public virtual Post ElectricPost { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit :** The interesting thing is I can get count of `Posts` without any problem and exception, but when I want to try the way in @HamletHakobyan post I'm getting `NullReferenceException` and I don't know why?

Comment: Similar Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462425/linq-get-total-count-of-values-from-nested-list

Comment: If you're getting a null reference exception, start your debugger, turn on First Chance exceptions, and find out.  Surely it's because someone didn't initialize a list property.

Comment: It's "Surname ", not "SureName". And if you use "FirstName" I think this should be "LastName".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure but try this:

```
var state = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
            .ObjectContext
            .CreateObjectSet<Province>("States") as ObjectQuery<Province>;
            // States is entitySetName

int count = state.Cities.Include("ElectricPosts.Employees")
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Posts)
                    .SelectMany(p => p.Employees)
                    .Count();
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply, but it throws an null reference exception, I'm using EF CodeFirst should I initialize Employees collection in Post Entity constructor?

Comment: @SaberAmani, filter null items out `.SelectMany(p => p.EmplEmployees).Where(m=> m != null).Count();`

Comment: @SaberAmani Sorry, i did not see the tag, i am not familiar with EF, but you can try query. Post updated.

Comment: Can you post your entities definitions? And exact exception with stack trace?

Comment: @SaberAmani I assume (because you didn't provide sources of your models) your `Post` class doesn't initialize `Employees` collection.

Comment: @SaberAmani Can you answer my above question? You can also provide sources of your models.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `DbSet<T>` doesn't contain `Include` method.

Comment: @SaberAmani If you use EF 5.0 there is extension method `Include`. If you use older version, see updated post. I think this will help you. Maybe you need correct something.

Comment: I'm using EF 5.0.0.0, but there is no method named Include

Comment: @SaberAmani [DbExtensions.Include<T> Method (IQueryable<T>, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696395(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ to Entities `Sum` and `Count` methods for this:

```
int count = db.States
  .Where( state => state.StateId == X )
  .Sum( state => state.Cities
    .Sum( city => city.Posts
      .Sum( post.Employees.Count() )
    )
  )
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from emp in dc.Employees
    from post in dc.Posts
    from city in dc.Cities
    from state in dc.States
    where emp.PostID == post.ID
    && post.CityID == city.ID
    && city.StateID == state.ID
    && state.Name == "Tehran"
    select emp;
```

or simply

```
var q = from emp in dc.Employees
    where emp.Post.City.State.Name == "Tehran"
```

**q** is the list of employees of that state and now you can easily count them (I'm sure you know how to count them).

Answer (score 1):

this would be my solution for your problem if i undersand you correctly
because i wasn't able to find a way to stick that 4 Linq together but maybe you are able to do this

by the way if you need optional where look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136896/linq-with-optional-where-clauses-and-sql-server-ce)

```
        var list = new List<Province>();

        string sProvinceName = "";
        string sCityName = "";
        string sPostName = "";
        string sEmployeeFirstName = "";
        string sEmployeeSureName = "";


        var iListListcitys = from province in list
                             where province != null
                             where province.Cities != null
                             where province.ProvinceName == sProvinceName
                             select province.Cities;

        var iListListposts = from icitys in iListListcitys
                             from city in icitys
                             where city != null
                             where city.ElectricPosts != null
                             where city.CityName == sCityName
                             select city.ElectricPosts;

        var iListListEmployees = from posts in iListListposts
                                 from post in posts
                                 where post != null
                                 where post.Employees != null
                                 where post.PostName == sPostName
                                 select post.Employees;

        var listEmployees = from employees in iListListEmployees
                            from employee in employees
                            where employee != null
                            where employee.FirstName == sEmployeeFirstName || employee.SureName == sEmployeeSureName
                            select employee;

        var count = listEmployees.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same (question) problem, but unfortunately the solutions that I found in Internet by the others were wrong! So I tried to solve this problem.
So, suppose that we have Some Countries that each Country has some States and Each State has some Cities, and we want to get some Countries View Models that have The Id and The name of each Countries and also the Count of all states and all cities belong to each country. The solution is below:

```
var varResult =
    OurDatabaseContext.Countries
    .Select(current => new {
        Id = current.Id,
        Name = current.Name,
        StateCount = current.States.Count,
        CityCount = current.States.Count == 0 ? 0 :
        current.States.Select(state =>
          new { CityCount = state.Cities.Count }).Sum(q => q.CityCount)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.States.Where(p => p.yourcondition == whatever).Cities.Posts.Employees.Count()
```

Comment: there are one-to-many relationship between them. you can not use States.Cities.Post

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Province province = ...;
int count = province.Cities.Include(c => c.Posts.Select(p => p.Employees))
    .Where(c => c != null)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Posts)
    .Where(p => p != null)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Employees)
    .Where(e => e != null)
    .Count();
```

Then remove the `.Where` clauses one by one to find the problematic place.

You can also use `join`s:

```
int count = (from c in province.Cities
             join p in db.Posts on c equals p.City
             join e in db.Employees on p equals e.ElectricPost
             select e).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cites = (from s in _db.Province where s.ProvinceName == 'name' select s.Cities);
int count = (from p in _db.Posts
         where city.Contains(p.City)
         select p.Employees).Count();
```